# How can I teach a plan to my blacksmith?

Tags: diablo-iii

I got a **Plan: Staff of herding** in the ACT IV. My Blacksmith is at level 4, but I tried to use it and didn't work.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Blacksmith and right click the Plan.

Comment: I'm in front my BS and right-click. it say "you can only use this item at the blacksmith"

Comment: Worked! (But I needed to open the forge to right-click)